# Batch 7zip, Zip file into archive without any folders

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am new to batch, and currently practicing to create automation script. I am stuck with this right now. I want the zip file to only contain tm_user.data, but my codes will archive it as Fame\tm_user.data. I would really appreciate if any of you could help me with this.

Variables

```
set default_folder_name=Main Folder
set tm_folder_name=TM Folder
set local_dir=C:\%default_folder_name%
set tm_dir=%local_dir%\%tm_folder_name%
```

Main body

```
set /p id="Enter ID: "
set d = "tm_user.data"

if exist "%tm_dir%\%id%\Fame\%d%" (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%tm_dir%\%id%\Fame\%id%_fame.zip" "%tm_dir%\%id%\Fame\%d%"
    echo Process completed...
    timeout 2
    start "launch folder" "%tm_dir%\%id%\Fame"
    exit
) else (
        echo Error: %d% not found, please try again later!!
        timeout 5
        exit
    )
)
```

Comment: Do not assign quotes to the variable. Also do not put spaces on either side of the equals symbol. `set d=tm_user.data`

Comment: ...or `set "d=tm_user.data"` (see the quotes which do not become bpart of the value here)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few best practices for batch files.

1. Don't not put spaces on either side of the equals symbol in the `SET` command. Spaces before the equals symbol become part of the variable name and spaces after the equal symbol get assigned to the variable.
2. Do not assign quotes to variables but do use them to surround the assignment to protect special characters and from assigning trailing spaces to the end of the variable.

I have chosen to use the `PUSHD` and `POPD` commands. The `PUSHD` command sets the working directory and stores the previous directory on the stack. The `POPD` command returns back to the previous stored directory. Using this technique you do not have to specify the paths within the 7zip command.

```
@echo off
set "default_folder_name=Main Folder"
set "tm_folder_name=TM Folder"
set "local_dir=C:\%default_folder_name%"
set "tm_dir=%local_dir%\%tm_folder_name%"

set /p "id=Enter ID: "
set "d=tm_user.data"

if exist "%tm_dir%\%id%\Fame\%d%" (
    pushd "%tm_dir%\%id%\Fame"
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%id%_fame.zip" "%d%"
    echo Process completed...
    timeout 2
    start .
    popd
    exit
) else (
    echo Error: %d% not found, please try again later!!
    timeout 5
    exit
)
```